# using jquery click to change a background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on what should be a rather simple thing, I want to click on the #new-quote button and have it's color change to a different color using jquery. The plan is to eventually have every non whitespace part of the webpage change to the same color on click. However I seem unable to get the simple task of changing one thing. I think the javascript is written correctly although maybe I made a mistake. I'm honestly just not sure why the button doesn't turn blue.

```
<body>
    <section class="quote-box row">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 id="quote"><i class="ion-quote quotes-icon"></i>Words have meanings! Or so people tell me I'm not sure!</h2></div>
        <div class="row"><h4 class="author">- Zack Fanning</h4></div>
        <div class="row buttons">
            <button id="twitter-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"><i class="ion-social-twitter twtter-button-icon"></i></a></button>
            <button id="new-quote">New quote</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="created-by row">
    <h4>By Zack Fanning</h4>
    </section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
</body>


$(document).ready(function(){

/* QUOTE ARRAY */
var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];

/* NEW QUOTE BUTTON */

$("#new-quote").click(function(){
   document.getElementById("#new-quote").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});  

};
```

Thank you to everyone I reworked my js file after reading the answers and now the code works beautifully

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/* QUOTE ARRAY */
var array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];

/* NEW QUOTE BUTTON */

var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange','black','blueviolet', 'brown', 'aqua', 'burlywood', 'coral', 'cyan', 'darkred', 'forestgreen', 'mediumvioletred', 'olivedrab', 'teal', 'yellowgreen'];

$("#new-quote").click(function(){

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
$(this).css('background-color', colors[rand]);
$("#quote").css('color', colors[rand]);
$(".author").css('color', colors[rand]);
$(".twtter-button-icon").css('background-color', colors[rand]);
$("#twitter-button").css('background-color', colors[rand]);
$("body").css('background-color', colors[rand]);


});  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working sample based on your example. A few things note:

- `document.getElementById()` accepts an id without a `#`
- since you're using jQuery, you could replace that with `$("#new-quote").css({backgroundColor: "blue"});`

  - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1 and http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* NEW QUOTE BUTTON */

  $("#new-quote").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("new-quote").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  });

});
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="quote-box row">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 id="quote"><i class="ion-quote quotes-icon"></i>Words have meanings! Or so people tell me I'm not sure!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h4 class="author">- Zack Fanning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
      <button id="twitter-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"><i class="ion-social-twitter twtter-button-icon"></i></a>
      </button>
      <button id="new-quote">New quote</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="created-by row">
    <h4>By Zack Fanning</h4>
  </section>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Later when I want to have an array of colors selected from, will it allow me to use an array[i] instead of "blue" or am I forced to declare the color?

Comment: @ZackLucky you can certainly pick from an array. See DaMaGeX's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35324929/26226

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    var colors = ['blue', 'red', '#0F0', 'rgb(123,45,67)'];
    $("#new-quote").click(function() {
      // Pick a random color
      var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
      // Set the background-color of the currently clicked element
      $(this).css('background-color', randomColor);
    });
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="quote-box row">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 id="quote"><i class="ion-quote quotes-icon"></i>Words have meanings! Or so people tell me I'm not sure!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h4 class="author">- Zack Fanning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
      <button id="twitter-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"><i class="ion-social-twitter twtter-button-icon"></i></a>
      </button>
      <button id="new-quote">New quote</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="created-by row">
    <h4>By Zack Fanning</h4>
  </section>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect this works, I'm kind of new when working using js with html would it allow me to use a variable for 'blue' because in the future I would like to use an array with colors to randomize the color.
Also do you know the way I could select the other elements?

Comment: Changed it to work for a random color from array. I recommend using jQuery over pure javascript since it's a lot easier and more logical programming in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The getElementById is a standard javascript function and receives the object id without the # selector. If you are using JQuery you should stick to it and take advantage of $(this) to select the button inside the click function.

Answer (score 0):

i) `document.getElementByID` is javascript, since you are using jquery you can do `$(this).css('background-color', 'blue');`. `$(this)` here refers to the element being clicked here.

ii) Since you would like to change the colors randomly, i have a list of colors in an **array**. and using `math.random()` we can get random number , to apply different colors.

You could try the below code, which lets u **apply random color to the button on every click**

**Javascript:**

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

$("#new-quote").click(function(){
   // Set the background-color of the currently clicked element
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 
   $(this).css('background-color', colors[rand]);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gpegnj0c/)